# quotes in queries

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have a mysql query which requires that parameters be enclosed in either "" or '',

if I have an array passed to this function:

```
function orderbyfield($column, array $selection)
{
 // will it be alright (secure) to do this?
 foreach ($selection as $s)
 {
  $s = '"' . $s . '"';
 }
 $string = implode(',', $selection)
 return array($column, $string);
}
```

and pass it to

```
function generate_sql()
{
 $fields = $this->orderbyfield(); // assuming the code is in a class
 $sql = 'SELECT FIELDS FROM TABLE ORDER BY FIELD (' . $fields[0] . ',' . mysql_real_escape_string($fields[1]));
}
```

will there be any security issues with this approach?

**EDIT**
assume that code is in a class, made necessary addition of $this->

**EDIT**
typo on the foreach

Comment: Looks like you have forgotten the parameters on the orderbyfield call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said you should be using mysql_real_escape_string *at the point where you create the query string*. Also, although the database may be able to cast between types, not all the variables need to be quoted in queries:

```
function enclose($val, $dbh)
{
  if (($val==='') || (is_null($val))) {
       return 'NULL';
  }
  // is it a number?
  if (preg_match('/^[\+-]*\d+\.?\d*$/', $val)) {
      return($val);
  }
  // its a string
  return("'" . mysql_real_escape_string($val, $dbh) . "'");
}
```

The null handling might need to be tweaked. (the above is cut down from a generic interface I use which also reads the structure of the table using DESCRIBE to get hints on when to quote/use nulls etc)

C.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the mysql_real_escape_string function, it is pretty safe as far as strings are concerned. See [dealing with sql injection](http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2009/09/08/preventing-sql-injection/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You should add quotes arround your string, but there quotes inside your strings themselves should also be escaped -- this can be done using [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string), [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), or [`PDO::quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php), depending on the kind of functions/methods you are using to connect to your database.

Doing this *(As you are already doing -- which is nice)* should prevent SQL injections *(at least for string : you should also check that numerics are indeed corresponding to numerical data, for instance)*

Another solution, maybe a bit easier once you get it, would be to use Prepared statements.

See :

- [`PDO::prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)
- or [`mysqli_prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)
- *(Those can't be used with the old `mysql_*` functions)*

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [PDO's prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), you do not have to worry about the escaping yourself. No quotes, no backslashes, no nothing.