# PHP MySQL query values when use implode() function

Tags: php, mysql, html

I've been using implode function of php and suddenly I encounter a problem regarding it.

```
<?php 
$insertValues[] = "(default,'{$y}', '{$p}', '{$o}', '{$i}', '{$u}','AMM-40','test')"; 

$query_status = "INSERT INTO `mobile1_mn1`.`logs_inbound` (
                  `log_id`, `originator`, `sender`, `date`, `time`,
                   `message`, `company_id`, `keyword`) 
                 VALUES". implode(',',$insertValues);
?>
```

When the information on `$y,$p,$o,$i` and `$u` does not have any single 'quotations' and commas it can save my information on database but when I have a string say for example the string is "he's good" and "Im, good" having a comma and quote it can't save my information anymore...

Comment: This might help clear things up a bit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137960/quotes-in-queries

Comment: What does this question to do with implode? do you have any problem with implode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to properly escape the string, use `mysql_real_escape_string`

The mysql_real_escape_string() function escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement

The following characters are affected:

- \x00
- \n
- \r
- \
- '
- "
- \x1a
  This function returns the escaped string on success, or FALSE on failure.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape SQL strings.
You can use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for this.

Comment: Escaping whatever "inputs" makes absolutely no sense. Escaping belongs to strings only and completely useless for any other "inputs". I hope eventually at least 10k+ folks will learn such a basic concept and refrain from writing misleading answers.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: All inputs are by default strings in php. So here input == string. I though that you would get it

Comment: I thought it is obvious that the topic in question is **mysql strings**, not *PHP variables*. Parts of the query that are enclosed in quotes. An number, when placed in the query without quotes, *although being of string type in PHP* will gain no benefit from escaping. Go figure. Not to mention silly "*user* unputs". As though non-user supplied strings require no escaping.

Comment: see your "escaping user inputs": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577833/something-is-wrong-with-my-code-and-i-dont-know-what

Answer (score 1):

use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Answer (score -1):

You have to put data/values that are STRINGS in quotes, so only imploding won't work here.