# Something is wrong with my code and i don't know what,

Tags: php, json

i'm trying to figure this out for days and i can't find what the error might be.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$page = isset($_POST['page']) ? intval($_POST['page']) : 1;
$rows = isset($_POST['rows']) ? intval($_POST['rows']) : 10;


include 'conn.php';




class get_data extends connection{

    public function __construct($page,$rows){
        $s_page=mysql_real_escape_string($page);
        $s_rows=mysql_real_escape_string($rows);



        $this->get_all($s_page,$s_rows);

    }


    public function get_all($page,$rows){
    $this->connect_to_db();
    $tablename = $this->define_table_name();
    $offset = ($page-1)*$rows;
    $result = array();


    $rs = mysql_query("select count(*) from $tablename");
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($rs);
    $result["total"] = $row[0];
    $startq="select * from $tablename limit $offset,$rows"; 
    $rs = mysql_query("select * from $tablename limit $offset,$rows");
    $items = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)){
    array_push($items, $row);
    }
    $result["rows"] = $items;

    echo json_encode($result);


    }

}

 $getdata=new get_data($page,$rows);
 ?>
```

The Output is `{"total":"3","rows":[]}`
**THE PROBLEM IS:** the rows are empty but it counts how many rows are in the db meaning that the connection is good but the query for the row is not working any suggestions?

Comment: what's in $items after the query? Can you post a var_dump() ?

Comment: array(0) { }  THis is on the var_dump of items

Comment: A suggestion OUt of this topic : Avoid Using "*" is queries use field names if few fields are needed

Comment: ok.. thanks @OMTheEternity, i was gonna improve security after this error. but it solved, i would now improve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are `mysql_real_escape_string`ing your parameters *before* establishing a connection to the database. `mysql_real_escape_string` needs an existing connection to the database to do its job. If there is none, it'll try to establish a connection by itself, which most likely fails, which means your parameters are `null`.

That should've been easy to figure out if you'd've enabled error reporting or would have debugged your app by simply `var_dump`ing various variables here and there.

Comment: waaah took me days to figure out this mess... Thanks That was good